# css sliding doors technique for animated loading bar

Tags: css

I have an image that I am using as a loading animation that is 755px wide.

http://www.salts-studios.com/resources/working_large.gif

The things is I have a requirement in one section of an app I am developing where the image width must be fluid.

IE 8 is the main supported browser (I know, I know) so scaling the image up when required isnt an option.

I cant change the image, but I could create a new additional one so long as it looked identical in style to the original.

Can anybody recommend any technique to achieve a fully fluid width?

I've tried various sliding door techniques but they fall over as the image is animated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a rather simple solution to this. In a parent div, set it to `width: 100%`, and set the child image also to `width: 100%`. Here's an example:

```
.bar {
  width: 100%;
}

.bar img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 19px;
}
```

And here's a [JSBin that has a working example](http://jsbin.com/edakug/1/edit)

Drag your browser window to different sizes and watch the image width resize. Let me know if this is what you were thinking should happen.

Comment: That actually looks like it will do the trick! It would appear I was trying to over engineer it.

Comment: We've all been in the over-engineering boat before. Glad it helped.